# How can i determine target control/window when WindowFromDC returns null?

Tags: winapi, hook, msdn, hwnd, gdi

I am new to win32 programming.I am intercepting an application from my application using `MadHookc`, by hooking `dll` funceions. I am hooking the `ExtTextOutW` function to get the text used for display in the application. Hookign `ExtTextOutW` gives me near about all the data of the hooked application. But my requirement is that, i need to know that the data coming in `ExtTextOutW` is going to set to which window/control( e.g. EditBox, Label,Button,List,combo,Frame,Tab etc.), so that i can process it according to my requirements. In some places i need to bypass the data of labels from my process. 
     My problem is that, in my hook i am getting parameters of `ExtTextOutW`. One of them is `HDC` , i know that if we call `WindowFromDC(hdc)` , will return the window name . But in some cases it returns `null`. So in that case i am not able to determine the control name.

```
BOOL WINAPI MyExtTextOutWHook(HDC hdc,int X,int Y,UINT fuOptions,CONST RECT *lprc,LPCWSTR lpString,UINT cbCount,CONST INT *lpDx)
{
     HWND currHwnd   = NULL;
     currHwnd = WindowFromDC(hdc);
     if(currHwnd != NULL)
     {
         //Get Control name from currHwnd . . .
     }
     else
     {
           // Not able to determine window/control name.
     }

}
```

I have referred many links like:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Microsoft_Development/Q_20336418.html

[WindowsFromDc return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167880/windowsfromdc-return-null)

which looks similer to my problem. But no one resolved my problem.

One of the ways i tried to determine control is that, i searched the methods called exactly before  `ExtTextOutW` of each control, hooked them and assigned a control name for the coming `ExtTextOutW` method.But some methods are same for more than one control, which causes the problem to differentiate between controls. Also doing this seems too lengthy and not able to get different method for each control  which calls before `ExtTextOutW` of that control.I searched for these methods in `User32.dll` and `GDI32.dll`. 
So does anyone has a different  suggestion or correction in my way. Any help would be appreciated.
 So can anyone help me out to differentiate controls. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hmya, you got a *lot* more hooking to do.  ExtTextOut() could also render to a printer for example.  You need to find out how the HDC got created to know.  So at a minimum also GetDC(), GetWindowDC() and BeginPaint() off the top of my head.

Comment: yes, @ Hans i know i just have started. No issue with printer because this application does not print anything.

Comment: @HansPassant, I also tried with hooking  BeginPaint method , but i observed that many times single BeginPaint is called for multiple ExtTextOutW's for defferent controls.Especially if a container window contains child windows then BeginPaint is called only for Container and not for Child controls.